# get values from label using JavaFx?

Tags: java, string, javafx, gettext

How can i get the value of  text-label, when i write to that label(txtName), when i press one button(whatever is it)i want to get that text to another method(in my case to method createPdf())? With txtName.getText() doesn't work?

```
  public void createPdf(){
     Document document = new Document();
    // FXMLDocumentController objFXML = new FXMLDocumentController();


     //String emriFajllit = objFXML.txtEmri.getText();

    try{
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(txtName.getText().toString()+".pdf"));
        document.open();



        document.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){ 
        System.out.println("Errori:"+e);

    }

}
```

Comment: Please add a bit more code like where you are setting text to the label. At the moment it is very hard to tell what the issue could be. My suggestion would be, if possible, post a majority of the code  so that the issue can be traced to somewhere.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If your label has a text, then you can get it with the getText() method. But labels are not meant to be used as input fields. You should use a TextField for that.

Comment: I'd take this a step further and use a `StringProperty nameProperty` which is bound the label and used for the Pdf name.  It's possible the label text isn't being used as an input, but still needs to change (for example if the name is generated with a date or sequence) you'd want to not use a TextField (and at that point anyone could argue for a textfield that is disabled).